# scroll and fix content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page that the text scrolls while the image remains fixed beside it, but only when the page reaches a certain point (scroll and fix content). So far, the javascript I am using is:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var height = $('body').height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > 519) {
          $('#leonardo').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top' : '74px' });
    } else {
        $('#leonardo').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top': '519px'});
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").animate({
         marginTop: "0"
    },2000);
});
```

CSS rules for the image I want to freeze are:

```
#leonardo {
    background-image:url(Images/Leonardo-Robot3%20Resized.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:300px;
    height:527px;
    float:left;
}
```

If possible, I want the image to change when each new header of the text is reached, like this example

(http://pitchfork.com/features/cover-story/reader/bat-for-lashes/)

Comment: You didn't post any of your html code so I'm not quite sure what's going on here but you are on the right track with position relative/fixed.  Remember though that position relative only works from within a parent who was position declared.  I'd recommend starting a jsFiddle with the skeleton of what you want.  That'll make it easier for people to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Jquery plugin might be useful http://nnattawat.github.io/fixedBG/